# Исключение при удалении таблицы, если её не существует

Tags: java, sql, исключения, jdbc

У меня есть метод который создает таблицу(jdbc)

```
String SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (" +
        "id serial," +
        "name varchar(100)," +
        "lastName varchar(100)," +
        "age integer)";
```

`IF NOT EXISTS` создаёт таблицу заново, если она существует (без ошибки).
А второй метод должен удалить таблицу, но, если еще раз его запустить то выбрасывается исключение: `"Такой таблицы не существует"`

Есть ли что-то типа `if not exist`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего имеется в виду конструкция `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, которая поддерживается многими серверами БД:

- mySQL [v 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html), [v.5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-droptable.html)
- [MS SQL (с версии 2016 13.x)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)